# How can I resize a Google Play Store badge to match an Apple App Store badge size of 200x83px?

Tags: html, web, formatting

Working on a website and I'm looking to resize a badge that's linked to the google play store. The code I'm using is:

```
<a href='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coachcare.robardionic&hl=en_US&gl=US&pcampaignid=pcampaignidMKT-Other-global-all-co-prtnr-py-PartBadge-Mar2515-1'>
  <img alt='Get it on Google Play' src='https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/static/images/badges/en_badge_web_generic.png'/>
</a>
```

And I'd like to resize to 200x83 px to match an Apple App Store badge.

This is the text for the Apple badge

```
<a href="https://apps.apple.com/us/app/myhealthyjourney/id1421821437?itsct=apps_box_badge&amp;itscg=30200" style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 13px; width: 250px; height: 83px;">
  <img src="https://tools.applemediaservices.com/api/badges/download-on-the-app-store/black/en-us?size=200x83&amp;releaseDate=1555027200" alt="Download on the App Store" style="border-radius: 13px; width: 250px; height: 83px;">
</a>
```

Every time I try to insert size parameters to the website it breaks the link. I'm new and am trying but I'm stumped.

I've tried copying the code from the working apple link and inserting it in different places but I feel like I'm missing a fundamental principal (or 4)

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. Note also that your example markup from Apple does not use one.

Answer (score 0):

Add style to the img.

```
<img style="height: 83px; width: 200px" alt='Get it on Google Play' src='https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/static/images/badges/en_badge_web_generic.png'/>
```